# Small white outline when exporting layers to file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, outline, error

When exporting by layers, all my PNG files contain a tiny white outline. I haven't found the cause of the problem, since when inside of Photoshop all my layers look fine, and no outline is to be seen.

[image]
[image]

These are the exporting settings I am using

[image]

My project also contains many folders, but I don't think it has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file type to PNG-24 and it should be fine.

From Adobe

> GIF and PNG‑8 formats support one level of transparency—pixels can be
> fully transparent or fully opaque, but not partially transparent. (By
> contrast, PNG‑24 format supports multilevel transparency; that is, you
> can have up to 256 degrees of transparency in an image, ranging from
> opaque to completely transparent.)

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/using-transparency-mattes.html